# Service Unavailable in Apache Coudstack

Tags: mysql, apache-cloudstack

I have installed Apache Cloudstack 4.11 on centos in **hyper-v**. After installation  by following steps and trying to access http://192.168.100.26:8080/client/ I am getting error:

> HTTP ERROR 503
>   Problem accessing /client/. Reason:
>   Service Unavailable

Steps link : [steps walk-through](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/quickinstallationguide/qig.html)

Here is the log:

```
    ERROR [c.c.u.d.Merovingian2] (main:null) (logid:) Unable to get a new db connection
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
        at com.cloud.utils.db.TransactionLegacy.getStandaloneConnectionWithException(TransactionLegacy.java:213)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
2020-03-20 18:48:43,140 WARN  [o.a.c.s.m.c.ResourceApplicationContext] (main:null) (logid:) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
2020-03-20 19:36:45,443 ERROR [c.c.u.d.Merovingian2] (main:null) (logid:) Unable to get a new db connection
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
        at com.cloud.utils.db.TransactionLegacy.getStandaloneConnectionWithException(TransactionLegacy.java:213)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
2020-03-20 19:36:45,446 WARN  [o.a.c.s.m.c.ResourceApplicationContext] (main:null) (logid:) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
2020-03-20 20:14:24,194 ERROR [c.c.u.d.Merovingian2] (main:null) (logid:) Unable to get a new db connection
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
        at com.cloud.utils.db.TransactionLegacy.getStandaloneConnectionWithException(TransactionLegacy.java:213)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'cloud'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-03-20 20:14:24,197 WARN  [o.a.c.s.m.c.ResourceApplicationContext] (main:null) (logid:) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'cloud'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-03-20 20:15:30,272 ERROR [c.c.u.d.Merovingian2] (main:null) (logid:) Unable to get a new db connection
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
        at com.cloud.utils.db.TransactionLegacy.getStandaloneConnectionWithException(TransactionLegacy.java:213)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'cloud'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-03-20 20:15:30,275 WARN  [o.a.c.s.m.c.ResourceApplicationContext] (main:null) (logid:) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lockMasterListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/cloudstack-management/lib/cloudstack-4.11.3.0.jar!/META-INF/cloudstack/system/spring-server-system-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.cloud.server.LockMasterListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to initialize a connection to the database for locking purposes
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'cloud'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Or maybe timezone is the isssue but dont know how to solve it.

> The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone.                                                                                                              You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' co                                                                                                             nfiguration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utili                                                                                                             ze time zone support.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I went through exact steps in the guide I've mentioned above.
OS CentOs 7, Couldstack 4.11

Answer (score 1):

Set the default time zone on MySQL Server itself:

in `/etc/my.cnf`:
under the `[mysqld]` section
add

```
default-time-zone='+00:00'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html